# Как в Wordpress красиво оформлять статьи

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой что когда я редактирую текст статью на сайте через WP, так там получается код, что то вроде:

```
<span style="font-family: georgia, palatino, serif; color: #333300; font-size: 12pt;">Тут текст</span>
```

Как сделать что бы WP запомнил мой выбор и было что то (и в css были стили)

```
<span class="shortText">Тут текст</span>
```

Или нужно весь код ручками переберать?

Comment: Хотите использовать классы вместо стилей, опишите стили этих классов в css файле и подключайте его.

Answer (score 0):

Вот неплохие плагины , попробуйте разобраться с ними, и будет вам счастье, они помогают стили ставить для определённого поста/страницы, если я правильно понял, то это как раз то что вы хотели найти.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-styling/
https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/

Comment: спасибо просмотрю